# R: geom_density values in y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why geom_density is showing me values higher than 1 in the density plot? How to change it into fraction?

[image]

And my code used to generate the plot

```
ggplot(data = input2, aes(x = r.close)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..density.., fill = `Próba`), alpha = 0.3, stat = "density", position = "identity") +

  xlab("y") + ylab("density") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size = rel(1.6), face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = "gray"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "gray90"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 13))
```

Comment: `geom_density(aes(y=..scaled..))`

Comment: Densities do not need to be less tahn 1. Probabilities do but probabilities are not defined for single points of continuous distributions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Or you can just used the computed `..scaled..` value `stat_density` provides:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
vals1 <- rbeta(1000, 0.5, 0.1)
vals2 <- rbeta(1000, 0.25, 0.3)

gg <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(vals1, vals2),
                        grp=c(rep("a", 1000), rep("b", 1000))))
gg <- gg + geom_density(aes(x=x, y=..scaled.., fill=grp), alpha=1/2)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the total area under the curve still higher than 1?

Comment: Just beware that this scaling makes no statistical/probabilistic sense whatsoever. Densities are not probabilities. As @Ben says, the area under the curve must be 1 for a density to be a density. The height of this curve is not a probability. The y values of the scaled curve are meaningless.  The correct answer is the one below.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like `geom_density()` is displaying the appropriate values. The area under that whole curve should be 1.

To get an estimate of the probability of certain values, you'd have to integrate over an interval on your 'y' axis, and *that* value should never be greater than 1.

Comment: So, what is currently displayed as the y-axis and how to show the probability?

Comment: Your y-axis is appropriately labeled - it is showing an approximate probability density curve for these data. A density curve can take on point values greater than one, but must be non-negative everywhere and the integral of the whole curve must be equal to one. Check out the Wikipedia article on [probability density functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). If you need the y-axis to be less than one, try a histogram with `geom_hist()`.

Comment: @DavidKent Using a histogram (the correct geom is named `geom_histogram()`, BTW) won’t help. A histogram is still a density estimate, and can have *y*-values greater than 1.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - it'll still sum to one with `aes(y=..density..)`. Would `geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../N))` work? Then the height of each bin would be the proportion of values that are in the bin's range?